# Clean keyframes not removing useless keyframes

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor, dopesheet

So I have been fiddling around with blender, and cannot figure out why the clean keyframes action is not acting as I expected. I have a light that is blinking, and there are some extra key frames in it. Once I press the clear keyframes button, it cleans up some, but not all of the useless keyframes. Why is this, and can I fix it?

Before Cleanup:

[image: Before]

After cleanup and setting to linear interpolation.

[image: After]

This is what I would have expected it to look like:

[image: Expected]

So to reiterate the question: Why is it not cleaning up as I expected, and is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: If a keyframe B is between two   keyframes A and C ,  and deemed on same line (within the threshold) it will be removed.  The two end points, that determine the line remain. Clearly demonstrated in question. .  For constant stepping like above a simple script would be my suggestion, removing any keyframe that has same value as previous.

Comment: So it only cleans if there are keyframes on both sides of the existing keyframe with the same value, as a test I just did with all three on a diagonal line does not have any affect either. This seems a bit limited, or am I missing another detail?